# regular expressions (HTML)

Tags: regex

I am trying to make pattern for 10 digits phone numbers like: `0547444333` or `054-7444333`
I've tried this expression:

```
/^(\d{10})|(\d{3}(-\d{7}))$/;
```

and it gave me true for both of the examples above. But even if I enter number like: `05474443332`
(11 digits) I get true also.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The alternation is applying to the anchors as well.

```
/^(\d{10}|\d{3}-\d{7})$/
```